# apt-get install old version proftpd

Tags: ftp, apt-get

I am looking to install proftpd 1.2.9.

I found the source in the [historic directories](ftp://ftp.servus.at/ProFTPD/historic/source/) of the proftpd site, however I cannot get it to compile. If need be, I can post the errors.. but there were a lot of them.

I -can- install proftpd with...

```
sudo apt-get install proftpd
```

But is there a way I can make `apt-get` install the older version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look into pinning and other advanced apt features, but it would probably be easiest to just download the .deb and install it with `dpkg -i`.

You'll have to do some of the dependency management by yourself though. If you run into dependency problems you'll probably be better off trying to compile it from source again.

Of course, you shouldn't be installing such an old version of that FTP daemon unless it's because you want to study its security problems ;).

Comment: Do you know where I could search for the .deb? (Tried google)
I might just have look into getting that source to compile..
thanks.

Comment: The 'normal' archives (even oldstable) don't back so far ( http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=proftpd-basic&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all ). In this case indeed I wouldn't bother looking for even older debs and return to trying to get the code to compile.

Answer (score 1):

No. You can sometimes install slightly older versions within the same Debian release, but certainly not that far back -- proftpd 1.2.9 was released in 2003; Debian has gone through a number of release cycles since then.